# Where is the default alarm clock melody stored on Android 4.1?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, ringtone, clock, media-files

I've bought a new Android smartphone (a T-Mobile branded Samsung Galaxy Note 3 SM-N9005, Android 5.0) and I don't really like it's default alarm clock ringtone. By countraries I like the default alarm clock ringtone of my old phone (Samsung Galaxy Ch@t B5330, Android 4.1) pretty much. I'd like to copy the old one to the new phone. But where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

```
/system/media/audio/alarms
```

Care to search?

Copy them to the Alarms directory under internal storage of your Note 3 - you should't need to put them into the same system location.